# Does DSE Graph/Search have the same asynchronous replication support as Cassandra?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I'm trying to build multiple datacenters and have asynchronous replication between them. I know Cassandra supports it just fine. Does the same multi-dc setup/configs that works for Cassandra work for DSE Graph/Search as well? Any extra setup required?

Answer (score 1):

DSE Graph is built on top of DSE version of Cassandra, so the replication is the same - use `replication` & `systemReplication` options when creating a graph (example from documentation):

```
system.graph('food').
  replication("{'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3 }").  
  systemReplication("{'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3 }").
  ifNotExists().create()
```

See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/system/refRF.html) for more details...